# Laravel array_sum Como obtengo el ultimo valor devuelto

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo el siguiente código en laravel el cual esta casi listo para la función que necesito

```
<td>
                        @php
                          $test = array();
                        @endphp
                         @foreach($lims_product_sale_data[$key] as $product_sale_data)
                        <?php 
                      
                         $cost = App\Product::select('cost')->find($product_sale_data->product_id);
                         if($product_sale_data->variant_id) {
                             $variant = App\Variant::find($product_sale_data->variant_id);
                             $product->name .= ' ['.$variant->name.']';
                         }
                         $unit = App\Unit::find($product_sale_data->sale_unit_id);
                       
                         $mult = $cost->cost * $product_sale_data->qty ;
                         array_push($test , $mult);
                        $fin[]=   array_sum($test);
                        $last = end($fin);
                        ?>
                     
                            
                       {{ $last}}
                      
                    
                        @endforeach
                    </td>
```

Esto se ejecuta en un blade de laravel debido a que me estoy apegando a un reporte anterior que muestra los datos exactamente como los necesito, ahora el problema que radica es que en la variable $mult esta hace la operación de multiplicar $cost por $product_sale_data->qty que es la cantidad vendida de productos.
Realizo un array push para agregar la variable mult en el array y luego usar array_sum para obtener la sumatoria del resultado de la multiplicación anterior.
Esta parte esta prácticamente casi lista, pero el problema es que en el array_sum me devuelve varios valores y no solo uno, como se ve en la imagen, el unico valor que necesito al final mostrar es el 12.86

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven también use la función end para intentar sacar ese ultimo valor pero aun así no funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Logre resolver era tema de orden en el código:

Hay que sacar del foreach la parte del array_sum y la impresión del mismo

```
 <td>
                        @php
                          $test = array();
                        @endphp
                         @foreach($lims_product_sale_data[$key] as $product_sale_data)
                        <?php 
                      
                         $cost = App\Product::select('cost')->find($product_sale_data->product_id);
                         if($product_sale_data->variant_id) {
                             $variant = App\Variant::find($product_sale_data->variant_id);
                             $product->name .= ' ['.$variant->name.']';
                         }
                         $unit = App\Unit::find($product_sale_data->sale_unit_id);
                       
                         $mult = $cost->cost * $product_sale_data->qty ;
                         array_push($test , $mult);
                       
                        ?>
                        @endforeach
                        @php
                        $fin[]=   array_sum($test);
                        $last = end($fin);
                        @endphp
                        {{ $last}}
                    </td>
```